# Does documentation in the form of HTML files work on github?

Tags: github

The documentation for my application is a set of HTML files. These HTML files are part of my git repo. If I put this project on github will people be able to view the HTML documentation files as rendered HTML rather than raw HTML?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no, github will not render HTML documentation/READMEs.

Long answer: 
Github uses this [code](https://github.com/github/markup) to render any README files. As you can see from its doc, it only supports the following rich texts formats:

- .markdown, .mdown, .md
- .textile
- .rdoc
- .org
- .creole
- .mediawiki
- .rst
- .asciidoc
- .pod

Although there are many HTML to *MARKUP_LANG* converters that may help you to some degree.

You can also consider using [Github Pages](http://pages.github.com) which will give you total control over the HTML/CSS/Js of the page.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Github documentation is in markdown. And HTML files as part of a repo display as raw HTML.

Alternatively, you could use [Github pages](http://pages.github.com/) to publish your documentation.

There are the various formats GitHub supports,

The following markups are supported. The dependencies listed are required if you wish to run the library.

```
.markdown, .mdown, .md -- gem install redcarpet (https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet)
.textile -- gem install RedCloth
.rdoc -- gem install rdoc -v 3.6.1
.org -- gem install org-ruby
.creole -- gem install creole
.mediawiki -- gem install wikicloth
.rst -- easy_install docutils
.asciidoc -- brew install asciidoc
.pod -- Pod::Simple::HTML comes with Perl >= 5.10. Lower versions should install Pod::Simple from CPAN.
```

Comment: lol, @Kay Zhu just added part of my answer (both of our answers were posted within seconds) to his as well.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to imply but I was editing my *already existing* post when your post didn't show up yet. It's only after I finished the edit did I refresh and see your post.

Comment: I was just pointing at the coincidence. Your answer showed up just as I posted as well :)